# How To Implement Import data Functionality With Golang?

Tags: rest, csv, go, go-gin

I have 2 methods, which I am using for `GET` and `POST`.
The first one is:

```
 var Join map[string]int

func MapTheFields(c *gin.Context) {
 var data []string
 //Open the csv file
 csvFile, _ := os.Open("customers.csv")
 reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
 line, _ := reader.ReadAll()
 for i := 0; i < len(line[0]); i++ {
     Join = map[string]int{
         line[0][i]: i,
     }
     data = append(data, line[0][i])
 }
 GetSuccessResponse(c, "The Mappings are:", data)

 }
```

Second one is also similar to the first. It just saves the values to the Database.

The problem I have been facing, is that I have to map the fields that I get from the csv file to the fields in my project, to do that I have made a map named `Join` as shown above and I am accessing the value of line in the second Function as

`line[i][Join["Last Name"]]`

But I am getting the value of `Join["Last Name"]` as `0` even though It's value is `1`, and wherever I am using the join as an index the value is zero and I always end up with only the first 4 values and then an index out of bounds error.

Rest Code Is:

```
func ImportCustomerData(c *gin.Context) {
//Open the csv file
csvFile, _ := os.Open("customers.csv")
reader := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
var (
    user      models.User
    customer  models.Customer
    address   models.UserAddress
    addresses []models.UserAddress
    people    []models.Customer
    users     []models.User
)

line, _ := reader.ReadAll()
for i := 1; i < len(line[0]); i++ {

    //Initialize address details

    address.Address = line[i][Join["address"]]
    address.City = line[i][Join["City"]]
    address.State = line[i][Join["State"]]
    address.Zipcode = line[i][Join["Postal Code"]]

    savedAddress := SaveNewAddress(address, merchantDb)

    //Initalize user details
    user.FirstName = line[i][Join["First Name"]]
    user.LastName = line[i][Join["Last Name"]]
    user.CompanyName = line[i][Join["Company Name"]]
    user.EmailId = line[i][Join["Email"]]
    user.PhoneNumber = line[i][Join["Phone"]]
  }
}
```

The OutPut Of The First Function in Postman Is:
`{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "api_status": 1,
        "message": "The Mappings are:",
        "data": [
            "First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Company Name",
            "Email",
            "Address",
            "City",
            "State",
            "Postal Code",
            "Phone",
            "Date Created",
            "Stripe ID",
            "Date of First Booking",
            "Date of Last Booking",
            "Frequency of Last Booking",
            "Date of Next Booking",
            "Notes",
            "Customer ID"
        ]
    }
}`

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: post rest of the code, by removing unnecessary details which aren't required..

Comment: Inside The For Loop of the rest code the index out of bound error is coming

Comment: Consider updating your first function code and then, specify what error you are getting now

Comment: i am not getting any output in postman

Comment: you are not creating new `user` on each iteration, and you are not appending it to `users`, check your logic.

Comment: i have removed that code as it was not neccesary its working fine the for loop is giving error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181345/discussion-between-nilsocket-and-harshit-vadhera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a new map each and every-time in `MapTheFields()`:

```
 for i := 0; i < len(line[0]); i++ {
     Join = map[string]int{
         line[0][i]: i,
     }
     data = append(data, line[0][i])
 }
```

`Join` map of type, should be allocated first, declare Join like this:

```
Join = make(map[string]int) //declaration can be global
```

Replace code snippet in `MapTheFields()` with this one:

```
 for i := 0; i < len(line[0]); i++ {
     Join[line[0][i]] = i
     data = append(data, line[0][i])
 }
```

Comment: @HarshitVadhera you need to allocate memory, using make, create Join using make

Comment: But i Want to access the value of join in the second Function thats Why I have Declared Globaly Join See Over The First Function

Comment: @HarshitVadhera If that's the case, declare `Join` globally, but assign locally in some function `Join = make(map[string]int)`, this will work

Comment: The Problem is Coming in the Second Function First is Fine